# Default Play framework code generates an error in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, playframework

I'm doing some research into the Play framework for Java. After creating a new project for Play 2.8 and opening the default HomeController.java file an error is generated stating a reference could not be resolved to a type.

Can anyone tell me why this is a problem and how to correct it?

Here's a screenshot:

[image: VS Code error indication]

Comment: Could you tag your IDE in the question please?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is that you are not importing the code generated via twirl that you'll found under target/twirl/main.
Try to mark `target/twirl/main` as source.

Beyond that i really suggest you to use intellij for your play project, just import it as sbt project and you are done